# Java ASM library for call trace instrumentation

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am following this tutorial [here](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~msb/cs239-tutorial/) and specifically I have trouble with the **Part 3: Call Trace Instrumentation**. I am still trying to wrap my head around visitor pattern and probably I have some error in the way I am trying to run this. My code is the following.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;

public class Copy {
    public static void main(final String args[]) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(args[0]);

        ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(is);
        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
        cr.accept(cw, 0);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
        fos.write(cw.toByteArray());
        fos.close();
    }

    class ClassAdapter extends ClassVisitor implements Opcodes {

    public ClassAdapter(final ClassVisitor cv) {
        super(ASM5, cv);
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(final int access, final String name,
            final String desc, final String signature, final String[]     exceptions) {
        MethodVisitor mv = cv.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature,     exceptions);
        return mv == null ? null : new MethodAdapter(mv);
    }
}

class MethodAdapter extends MethodVisitor implements Opcodes {

    public MethodAdapter(final MethodVisitor mv) {
        super(ASM5, mv);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name,     String desc, boolean itf) {
        /* System.err.println("CALL" + name); */
        mv.visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "err",     "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
        mv.visitLdcInsn("CALL " + name);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println",     "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);

        /* do call */
        mv.visitMethodInsn(opcode, owner, name, desc, itf);

        /* System.err.println("RETURN" + name);  */
        mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "err",     "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
        mv.visitLdcInsn("RETURN " + name);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream",     "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
    }
}
}
```

I am running this as in the previous example of this tutorial with 
`javac -cp asm-all-5.0.3.jar Copy.java`

I seem to be unable what I am doing wrong and the results of the errors I put them [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/j66bgmrg) for cleaner looks.

Comment: Please include the whole error message.

Comment: @JornVernee have updated the question with a link to all the errors appeared.

Comment: According to your posted code, you are importing `org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader` and `org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter`, but not, e.g. `org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor`. But it’s not clear, how you got the compiler complaining about classes in `jdk.internal.org.objectweb.asm.*`; these classes should not be in your source path at all.

Comment: The code forgets to actually use ClassAdapter - you should use it to wrap the cw when calling `cr.accept(...)`.